# ARM64 translation table sizes

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm64, mmu, virtual-address-space

I recently took a look at the config file of my ARM64 linux kernel and noticed that the following options are set :-

```
CONFIG_ARM64_4K_PAGES=y
CONFIG_ARM64_VA_BITS_48=y
CONFIG_ARM64_VA_BITS=48
```

Looking at slide 8 [here](https://events.linuxfoundation.org/images/stories/pdf/lcna_co2012_marinas.pdf), I see that a 4KB page size and a 48 bit VA means that there are 4 levels of translation. So I look at the Aarch64 reference manual.

For convinience, I have uploaded a picture from page 1718 of the [reference manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/ca/DDI0487C_a_armv8_arm.pdf).

[image: Translation]

I can see that the index to the translation table at each level is 9 bits(except at the last level). As a result, the zero, first, and second translation table should be able to index 2^9 values.

My doubts are :-

1. What is the size of each item inside the zero, first, second and third translation table?
2. How did you obtain this information / arrive at this conclusion?

[EDIT]
Correct the number of bits from 8 to 9.

Comment: What does "the size of each item" mean? The size of a PTE? the size of a table? The amount of address space covered by an entry at each level (i.e. the block size)? Also, count again; it's not 8 bits per level.

Comment: @Notlikethat Thanks. I have changed from 8 to 9 bits. Yes, I mean the size of each entry(PTE), at different translation table levels.

Comment: Given that you're quoting the architecture manual, you have read D5.3 and D5.4, right? Perhaps unsurprisingly, AArch64 PTEs are 64 bits. Sorry, but I'd file that under "trivially obvious".

Comment: Thanks, if you can add that as an answer i can accept